# cada vez que intento hacer una build de mi app en flutter, me da este error

Tags: android, flutter

estoy aprendiendo flutter y estaba haciendo una app de prueba, primero funcionaba perfectamente y entonces se me ocurrió cambiarle un poco las fuentes, para ello me descargue el paquete de google_fonts para flutter. Ahora cada vez que intento hacer una build de mi app para probarla, me sale este error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Go in debug mode...
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
ERROR:E:\Documents\p\next\f\Flutter_test\notes\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke &quot;String.length()&quot; because &quot;&lt;parameter1&gt;&quot; is null
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task &#39;:app:mergeDexDebug&#39;.
&gt; Could not resolve all files for configuration &#39;:app:debugRuntimeClasspath&#39;.
   &gt; Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      &gt; Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: E:\Documents\p\next\f\Flutter_test\notes\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         &gt; Error while dexing.

* Try:
&gt; Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
&gt; Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
&gt; Run with --scan to get full insights.
&gt; Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

before i installed the package, it worked quite good

intente poniendo esto en el archivo build.gradle de la carpeta app pero no solucionó absolutamente nada

```
dependencies {
  implementation &#39;com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1&#39; 
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: Probaste escribir `implementation "com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1"` ?

Comment: @Mateo Si ya lo hice y sigue saliendo el mismo error